# Way to cache a query for 24 hrs

Tags: query-posts

Would like to show a random tip from tips category in wordpress and change it every 24hrs... is it possible?

Here is my query

```
// Random post link 
function randomPostlink(){
$RandPostQuery = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>array('tip'),'posts_per_page' => 1,'orderby'=>'rand'));
while ( $RandPostQuery->have_posts() ) : $RandPostQuery->the_post();
echo the_permalink();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534182/is-there-a-way-to-cache-a-query-for-24-hrs-in-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WP_Object_Cache](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/) combined with a persistent cache plugin or you can use [Transient API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

**WP_Object_Cache:**

```
// Random post link 
function randomPostlink(){

    $cache = wp_cache_get( 'random_tip_link' );

    if( $cache ) {

        echo $cache;

    } else {

        ob_start();

        $RandPostQuery = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>array('tip'),'posts_per_page' => 1,'orderby'=>'rand'));

        while ( $RandPostQuery->have_posts() ) {

              $RandPostQuery->the_post();

              echo the_permalink();

        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        $cache = ob_get_flush();
        wp_cache_set( 'random_tip_link', $cache );

   }

}
```

**Transient API:**

```
// Random post link 
function randomPostlink(){

    $cache = get_transient( 'random_tip_link' );

    if( $cache ) {

        echo $cache;

    } else {

        ob_start();

        $RandPostQuery = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>array('tip'),'posts_per_page' => 1,'orderby'=>'rand'));

        while ( $RandPostQuery->have_posts() ) {

              $RandPostQuery->the_post();

              echo the_permalink();

        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        $cache = ob_get_flush();
        set_transient( 'random_tip_link', $cache, DAY_IN_SECONDS );

   }

}
```

If you need to cache the query with or without persistent cache plugin, use Transient API which use database for cache results and if a persistent cache is enabled it will use WP_Object_Cache: